# How to display an Image in Button?

Tags: java, android, button

I have this code in my activity_login.xml.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#6cb42e"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:icon="@drawable/tasto_login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want to show the image tasto_login.png in the right on the button.
In this button I want a background color, text center and image at right of the button.

So with this code, I don't see any image.

I show it:
[image]

but I want have this:
[image]

Comment: try to use imagebutton or textview with drwable and you can achieve above requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the existing code, you can just use `drawableRight` like:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#6cb42e"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/tasto_login"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Add `paddingRight` to modify where the icon is placed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take background image like this.and set this image as background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Layout as button:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#6cb42e"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="login"
android:orientation="horizontal"
       >

<Textview


/>

<ImageView

/>

</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Button using Linearlayout and TextView :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/customButton1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#6cb42e"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="login">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/tasto_login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property of button itself as

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/tasto_login"
```

This will add the image to right of the text in your utton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:drawableRight` xml attribute to specify the image. 
Also you can use the `android:drawablePadding` and other padding/margin attributes to position the image on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace android:icon="@drawable/tasto_login" with android:drawableRight="@drawable/tasto_login"
and set padding with android:drawablePadding